# Assigning results of a for loop to an empty matrix

Tags: r, object, loops

I have another question for the brilliant minds out there (this site is so addictive).

I am running some simulations on a matrix and I have nested for loops for this purpose.  The first creates a vector that increases by one each time a loop cycles.  The nested loop is running simulations by randomizing the vector, attaching it to the matrix, and calculating some simple properties on the new matrix.  (For an example, I used properties that will not vary in the simulations, but in practice I require the simulations to get a good idea of the impact of the randomized vector.)  The nested loop runs 100 simulations, and ultimately I want only the column means of those simulations.

Here's some example code:

```
property<-function(mat){                       #where mat is a matrix
  a=sum(mat) 
  b=sum(colMeans(mat))
  c=mean(mat)
  d=sum(rowMeans(mat))
  e=nrow(mat)*ncol(mat)
  answer=list(a,b,c,d,e)
  return(answer)
  }

x=matrix(c(1,0,1,0, 0,1,1,0, 0,0,0,1, 1,0,0,0, 1,0,0,1), byrow=T, nrow=5, ncol=4)

obj=matrix(nrow=100,ncol=5,byrow=T)            #create an empty matrix to dump results into

for(i in 1:ncol(x)){                           #nested for loops
  a=rep(1,times=i)                             #repeat 1 for 1:# columns in x
  b=rep(0,times=(ncol(x)-length(a)))           #have the rest of the vector be 0
  I.vec=append(a,b)                            #append these two for the I vector
    for (j in 1:100){
      I.vec2=sample(I.vec,replace=FALSE)       #randomize I vector
      temp=rbind(x,I.vec2)
      prop<-property(temp)
      obj[[j]]<-prop
      }
  write.table(colMeans(obj), 'myfile.csv', quote = FALSE, sep = ',', row.names = FALSE)
  }
```

The problem I am encountering is how to fill in the empty object matrix with the results of the nested loop.  obj ends up as a vector of mostly NAs, so it is clear that I am not assigning the results properly.  I want each cycle to add a row of prop to obj, but if I try

```
obj[j,]<-prop
```

R tells me that there is an incorrect number of subscripts on the matrix.

Thank you so much for your help!

**EDITS:**
Okay, so here is the improved code re the answers below:

```
property<-function(mat){                       #where mat is a matrix
  a=sum(mat)
  b=sum(colMeans(mat))
  f=mean(mat)
  d=sum(rowMeans(mat))
  e=nrow(mat)*ncol(mat)
  answer=c(a,b,f,d,e)
  return(answer)
  }

x=matrix(c(1,0,1,0, 0,1,1,0, 0,0,0,1, 1,0,0,0, 1,0,0,1), byrow=T, nrow=5, ncol=4)

obj<-data.frame(a=0,b=0,f=0,d=0,e=0)            #create an empty dataframe to dump results into
obj2<-data.frame(a=0,b=0,f=0,d=0,e=0)

for(i in 1:ncol(x)){                           #nested for loops
  a=rep(1,times=i)                             #repeat 1 for 1:# columns in x
  b=rep(0,times=(ncol(x)-length(a)))           #have the rest of the vector be 0
  I.vec=append(a,b)                            #append these two for the I vector
    for (j in 1:100){
      I.vec2=sample(I.vec,replace=FALSE)       #randomize I vector
      temp=rbind(x,I.vec2)
      obj[j,]<-property(temp)
      }
  obj2[i,]<-colMeans(obj)
  write.table(obj2, 'myfile.csv', quote = FALSE,
  sep = ',', row.names = FALSE, col.names=F, append=T)
  }
```

However, this is still glitchy, as the myfile should only have four rows (one for each column of x), but actually has 10 rows, with some repeated.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `property` function is returning a list. If you want to store the numbers in a matrix, you should have it return a numeric vector:

```
property <- function(mat)
{
  ....
  c(a, b, c, d, e)  # probably a good idea to rename your "c" variable
}
```

Alternatively, instead of defining `obj` to be a matrix, make it a `data.frame` (which conceptually makes more sense, as each column represents a different quantity).

```
obj <- data.frame(a=0, b=0, c=0, ...)
for(i in 1:ncol(x))
  ....
  obj[j, ] <- property(temp)
```

Finally, note that your call to `write.table` will overwrite the contents of `myfile.csv`, so the only output it will contain is the result for the last iteration of i.

Comment: Fantastic!  Thank you for all of this advice.

Comment: I can fix the overwrite problem by adding in "append=T".  obj works properly now, but the file produced write.table was still only one column.  I fixed this by creating a second empty dataframe with the colMeans of obj as rows and then wrote that to an csv file.

Answer (score 2):

Use [rbind](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/cbind.html):

```
 obj <- rbind(obj, prop)
```